# ReadTheDocs downloads wrong package

Tags: python, easy-install, read-the-docs

Basically, the issue I'm having is that my package requires both `click` and `click-default-group`. However, during build, when ReadTheDocs tries to install `click`, it ends up installing `click-default-group` instead and then raising an error that `click` was never installed:

```
Searching for click_default_group
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/click_default_group/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/3e/389d8bbe3033613b17ce4136dbcf3e69c785c9c54d08f3adb95336b52040/click-default-group-1.2.tar.gz#sha256=ba8c43d9c384e1ea7127484c5fc8f4e1ca759519a64fff10718d53f4b82c412a
Best match: click-default-group 1.2
Processing click-default-group-1.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-eo0ffsj2/click-default-group-1.2/setup.cfg
Running click-default-group-1.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-eo0ffsj2/click-default-group-1.2/egg-dist-tmp-lwzhnf1c
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving click_default_group-1.2-py3.5.egg to /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Adding click-default-group 1.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click_default_group-1.2-py3.5.egg
```

...

```
Searching for click
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/3e/389d8bbe3033613b17ce4136dbcf3e69c785c9c54d08f3adb95336b52040/click-default-group-1.2.tar.gz#sha256=ba8c43d9c384e1ea7127484c5fc8f4e1ca759519a64fff10718d53f4b82c412a
Best match: click default-group-1.2
Processing click-default-group-1.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-sti3nr59/click-default-group-1.2/setup.cfg
Running click-default-group-1.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-sti3nr59/click-default-group-1.2/egg-dist-tmp-58ldag5e
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Removing /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click_default_group-1.2-py3.5.egg
Moving click_default_group-1.2-py3.5.egg to /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages
click-default-group 1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click_default_group-1.2-py3.5.egg
error: The 'click' distribution was not found and is required by click-default-group, freqgen
```

As can be seen, it says that the best match for `click` is `click default-group-1.2`, which it is not.

For reference, the full build log can be seen [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/freqgen/builds/7692314/).

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by specifying the exact version of `click` that I wanted to use:

```
Searching for click>=6.7
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/click/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/c1/8806f99713ddb993c5366c362b2f908f18269f8d792aff1abfd700775a77/click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=29f99fc6125fbc931b758dc053b3114e55c77a6e4c6c3a2674a2dc986016381d
Best match: click 6.7
Processing click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/freqgen/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Adding click 6.7 to easy-install.pth file
```

No idea as to the origin of the issue, but it seemed to fix it.